# How to import AlertDialog in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, user-interface

I tried to google my problem but I couldn't found it, that's why I ask.

**Error: unresolved reference: AlertDialog**

**Question:** How to import AlertDialog because if I google it then I see different methods that causing the error above, e.g. `import android.app.AlertDialog` or `import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` or something else, I need something universal that will never break. I'm wondering why the `#include <...>` in C++ never get expired and lasts for many years.

Import from https://geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-custom-yes-no-dialog-in-android-with-kotlin/

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
```

Import from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-alert-dialog-box-in-android/

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
```

Import from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-alert-dialog-using-kotlin

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

**Code in "MainActivity.kt" (Kotlin with C++ in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1)**

```
package com.emcengine.emceditor

import android.app.NativeActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Context
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.view.KeyEvent
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue

//_/--------------------------------------------------\_
import android.app.AlertDialog // error: unresolved reference: AlertDialog
// \--------------------------------------------------/

class MainActivity : NativeActivity() {
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun showSoftInput() {
        val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this.window.decorView, 0)
    }

    fun hideSoftInput() {
        val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.window.decorView.windowToken, 0)
    }

    // Queue for the Unicode characters to be polled from native code (via pollUnicodeChar())
    private var unicodeCharacterQueue: LinkedBlockingQueue<Int> = LinkedBlockingQueue()

    // We assume dispatchKeyEvent() of the NativeActivity is actually called for every
    // KeyEvent and not consumed by any View before it reaches here
    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            unicodeCharacterQueue.offer(event.getUnicodeChar(event.metaState))
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }

    fun pollUnicodeChar(): Int {
        return unicodeCharacterQueue.poll() ?: 0
    }

    //_/--------------------------------------------------\_
    fun messageBox() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder // error: unresolved reference: AlertDialog
        //builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    }
    // \--------------------------------------------------/
}
```

Comment: That's not c++ code, pick a correct language tag.

Answer (score 3):

In general: You don't have to add the imports by hand. AndroidStudio does all that for you when you just reference another class etc. Try it by removing the import and simply typing `AlertDialog` somewhere. Then select it from the list of suggestions in the dropdown.

The one you are probably looking for is `import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`.

Also, in Kotlin the type stands after the variable name (and is optional in that case):

```
val builder: AlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

Comment: I tried to type AlertDialog somewhere that has a message "Unresolved reference: AlertDialog" and the tooltip has blue texts "Create class 'AlertDialog' " (Alt+Shift+Enter) and "More actions... (Alt+Enter)". I tried to click on "Create class 'AlertDialog' " but it creates an empty class, and I tried to click on "More actions..." but all I see in a list is about Create class/enum/interface/local variable/object/parameter/property and Rename reference, and I don't know where is the list item that should fix my problem about import AlertDialog?

Comment: Hm, then you are missing a certain dependency. You can try to add `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'` to your `build.gradle` of the app module, sync the project and then try again?

Comment: I tried to create a completely new project (Native C++ with Java language) then the first time I write AlertDialog then it appears on the list not like in my project. But when I tried to create a Native C++ with Kotlin language then there are so many errors. Maybe because Kotlin needs download from the internet, maybe missing download. But I need time.

Comment: Kotlin is already bundled with Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
```

Old `AlertDialog` class, shouldn't be used anymore. Still there for retrocompatibility purposes.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
```

`AlertDialog` that works on both old and new Android versions while supporting the new API. This requires a new dependency on the support v7 library.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
```

Android X (aka new SDK) `AlertDialog`. This is the one you want to use.

[More on this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library)

Comment: Who knows, maybe because AlertDialog class is old then it becomes impossible to automatically fix the error message (Unresolved reference: AlertDialog), I'm not sure. I added a comment about it in other comment in this thread. Can you suggest an alternative to AlertDialog?

Comment: Use this import: import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog. In any case Android Studio should already help you with the correct import if you alt click the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is an important thing to know if you're doing Android development: there are a whole lot of versions of Android out there, because many devices stop getting updates after only a few years. That means new Android features, and updates and fixes for old features, just don't exist on a lot of devices.

That's a problem when you're trying to write software that works on all those devices - some stuff just won't be available. Some stuff will work differently, or display differently. Some stuff will have bugs that were fixed in later versions, and you'll have to work around those.

At best, you'll have to do a lot of *if the API version is between this and this* checks, with different code paths for different versions. At worst, some things won't be available at all, and you'll have to decide between not using those features, locking your app to the range of devices where it *is* available, or effectively making multiple versions of your app. And then you have to test it all too!

---

So what some very nice people at Android produced is the [*Support Library*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library). This basically backports features and fixes so they're available on older devices, instead of only being able to use the stuff baked into the version of the OS they have. It also gives you a common interface for those features - you don't need to use a `Compat` library for old APIs and the system version for newer ones, you just use the `Compat` version and that's it. It'll work out what to do internally, you don't need to worry about it.

They also test all these features, so you can assume they Just Work on every API - you don't need to do special testing to see if your own workarounds are being handled correctly, someone's already done that for the Support Library implementations!

---

So it's recommended standard practice to *always* use the Support Library in your Android projects, and always use its implementation for things over the standard library ones. That's why your `Activities` inherit from `AppCompatActivity` and not `Activity`, and why the `Fragment` class that gets automatically imported is the `androidx` one, and not the standard `Fragment` (which was actually [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment?hl=en) several versions ago)

As for your imports, the trouble is you're reading tutorials and guides that are years apart, and things change. [*m0skit0*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74508185/13598222) explains what each version is - but basically the `support` library is deprecated, and you want the new [AndroidX/Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) versions of things.

AndroidX is a little different, instead of one big support library (which got broken into a handful of still big support libraries by API version) it's much more granular. That means you have to install the specific libraries you want. [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.Builder) (and the [*Material Design version*](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder)) are part of the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` library (top of the page, or in the package name) - so you need to [add that as a dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#declaring_dependencies), and that's the import you'll use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Code for Alert Box

MainActivity.kt

```
    val alertBTN = findViewById<Button>(R.id.alertBtn)

    alertBTN.setOnClickListener {

        val alertMessage = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)

        alertMessage.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to exit?")
        alertMessage.setTitle("Exit?")
        alertMessage.setCancelable(false)
        alertMessage.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            finish()
        }

        alertMessage.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
        alertMessage.setNeutralButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        val alertDialogBox = alertMessage.create()
        alertMessage.show()

    }
```

main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alert Box "
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.102" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/alertBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.572" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).